# How to add both a partial and full index to a single column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, indexing

I'm trying to index a table I have on a single column using both a full index, and a partial index inside a create_table block like so:

```
t.index [:streamer_id], :name => "index_referral_programs_on_streamer_id"
t.index [:streamer_id], :where => "active is true", :unique => :true, :name => "index_active_referral_programs_on_streamer_id"
```

however, only the second index is added to my schema after migrating. Is it possible to have both a partial and full index on a single column? And if so, how can I go about achieving that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using those two lines in a single migration in a `change_table` block works fine.  Adding them in a `create_table` block doesn't work.

Based on [the source of ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition#index](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a61e4ae58d65d43a97e90bdb02b6c407791e3c53/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L323-L329), this is a limitation of the `create_table`-scoped `index` function.  Adding them directly in the `create_table` seems unidiomatic anyway.  I'd suggest:

```ruby
create_table :referral_programs do |t|
  # whatever columns you need in the table
end
add_index :referral_programs, [:streamer_id], name: "index_referral_programs_on_streamer_id"
add_index :referral_programs, [:streamer_id], where: "active is true", unique: true, name: "index_active_referral_programs_on_streamer_id"
```

Comment: Thanks benizi! That was the problem.